# display the tier prices text in a single line in product view page

Tags: css, html, tierprice

please check this link : http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/happy-hours-scribblez.html

below price you can see "Buy 5 for Rs100.00 each and save 70%"

i want to dispaly the text in one line

please help me to find solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a plain HTML/CSS question

Comment: @fschmengler but it is a megnto site related question. if you still think you want to close, its your wish. i will respect your decision.

Comment: Not that it matters anymore in this case but lot's of questions about how to change some CSS on a particular site that happens to run Magento are not relevant to any other Magento users and IMHO out of scope here.

Comment: okay from next time, i will try to ask questions that going be to helpfull for all users.

Comment: No need to be sarcastic. (or are you serious about it? in that case, thumbs up)

Comment: No, i am serious about it, I really did't said in sarcastic way, if you want, i will delete this question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text does not fit on the same row because there is no room for it.
You have 2 boxes with classes `Quick_1` and `Quick_2`. THe first one is 40% wide and the second one 55% wide.
Make them 49% (or 48..see what fits your needs) and the text might fit.

Comment: i changed to 48 %, now its coming in one line ,but the second column went below.

before it was like this : http://hotwheelstoys.in/mobileapp2/peacock-bebe-blocks-set-no-7.html

now http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/happy-hours-scribblez.html# what changes i have to do to display properly.

Comment: Try to change the width of the second column also. The sum of the widths of the blocks should not be over 100%. It should actually be around 96-98 % because you also have some margins.

Comment: sorry , i changed 48 to 40 %, now it seems fine. can you please check once

Comment: If you say it works, I don't need to check :)

Comment: if you entered the question means , that time itself, i feel this is going to solve.....